# How do I decouple business logic from UI in React?

Tags: reactjs

When working on a bigger React project I often run into a situation similar to the following:

I have an upload component for multiple files. I need to

- do some time-consuming checks whether the file is even suitable for upload,
- track the progress of the upload,
- report errors during the upload,
- etc..

I would like to have a data structure like this:

```
[
  {
    fileName: 'something.txt',
    uploadable: 'checking',
    progress: 'not-started',
  },
  {
    fileName: 'something.else',
    uploadable: 'no',
    progress: 'cancelled',
  },
  {
    fileName: 'anything.else',
    uploadable: 'yes',
    progress: '50%',
  },
]
```

I don't want the update logic for this structure inside my React component as the logic can be rather complex. But when the structure changes, my component should rerender. So I imagine some custom hook like this

```
import useFileList from 'my-file-list-logic';

const FileList = () => {
  const list = useFileList();

  return (
    <some nice UI for the files />
  )
}
```

But then I don't know how to connect the buttons in my component to the business logic.

I looked a little into libraries like Redux, MobX and Recoil but I am a bit confused  whether they are suited/intended for this kind of scenario.

Comment: there can be numerous answer to your question based different use cases. Either write specific use case or all that you need.

Comment: The use case is rather general as I encountered this kind of situation many times already. Every time I have an object that I want to display in a React component. I want the component to rerender when the object changes based on some business logic triggered from within or outside of the component.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach,

A simple answer is to keep your data in separate JSON file and add logics in different file. and main logic in different file. Yiu can try `fs` Module to read file or even directly at some places using relative path.